# Динамический массив не заполняется. Не могу понять почему

Tags: c++, массивы, динамические-массивы

Пытаюсь перевести из string в int и в коде столкнулся с тем, что динамический массив по какой-то причине не заполняется. Вернее заполняется лишь одна ячейка. Никак не могу понять, что не так. Вроде прогоняю через for, размер массива не равен единице. Но каждый раз он взамен старому число перезаписывает новое.
Знаю, что можно воспользоваться готовыми функциями. Но хотелось как-то самому голову поломать. А потом  уже и с функциями разобраться. Вроде через atoi.

```
int string_to_number(const std::string& s) {
    int strnum = s.size();
    int *ary = new int[strnum];//этот массив не заполняется
    int *ary2 = new int[strnum];//этот просто задел на будущее
    int digits[10] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    int digits2[10] = { 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57 };
    int digits3[10] = { 1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000, 10000000, 100000000, 1000000000 };
    for (int a = 0; a < strnum; a++) {
        ary[a] = s[a];//и здесь каждый раз заново заполняется лишь одна ячейка, вместо 4х
    }
    for (int a = 0; a < strnum; a++) {
        for (int b = 0; b < 10; b++) {
            if (ary[a] == digits2[b]) {
                ary[a] = digits[b];
            }
        }
    }
    for (int a = 0; a < strnum; a++) {
        for (int b = strnum; b > 0; b--) {
            ary[a] = ary[a] * digits3[b];
        }
    }
    int result = 0;
    for (int a = 0; a < strnum; a++) {
        result = result + ary[a];
    }
    delete[] ary;
    delete[] ary2;
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    std::string str = "1234";
    std::cout << "Size of string is " << str.size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << string_to_number(str) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Для размеров строки и счётчиков лучше использовать тип `std::string::size_type` или `std::size_t`, а не `int`

Comment: Запустил Ваш код в Qt. Массив `ary` заполняется корректно. Правда, увидел это только после того, как указал каждую ячейку по отдельности в отслеживаемых значениях. Просто по имени  `ary` отображалась в отладке только первая ячейка. А вот в цикле, где Вы умножаете на элементы массива `digits3` умножение выполняется многократно, вызывая переполнения во всех ячейках массива `ary`

Comment: *Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.* - где тут описание желаемого поведения? :) Что ваша программа вообще должна делать?

Comment: Спасибо за информацию! Да, действительно. Помню видел как использовали эти типы в других кодах. В ответ на @dIm0n. Пока ещё не разобрался как работает здесь система комментариев.

"Правда, увидел это только после того, как указал каждую ячейку по отдельности в отслеживаемых значениях." - то есть я не правильно понял отладчик и заполнение работало корректно?
"А вот в цикле, где Вы умножаете на элементы массива digits3 умножение выполняется многократно, вызывая переполнения во всех ячейках массива ary" - да, я заметил. Но в отладчике столкнулся в первую очередь с тем, что массив не заполнялся

Comment: @Witson мне пришло уведомление, всё норм https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment

Comment: и видимо я ошибся? В ответ на комментарий @ЮрийКозлов

Comment: А, теперь разобрался как работает система.
Спасибо! @dIm0n

Comment: "Пытаюсь перевести из string в int и в коде столкнулся с тем, что динамический массив по какой-то причине не заполняется" - написал я в шапке. Честно говоря не понимаю что подробнее стоили мне описать.
Хотел чтобы массив заполнился корректно и перевести строку "1234" в int. То есть массив ary судя по отладчику заполнял лишь одну ячейку, вместо 4х. И я не мог понять отчего. В ответ @Harry

Comment: @Witson, Не знаю, какой средой Вы пользуетесь, и как там работает отладчик. У меня в окне просмотра переменных показывает только первую ячейку `ary`, а если в окне вычисляемых выражений задать по отдельности `ary[0] .. ary[3]` то видно ,что заполняются и изменяются все ячейки.

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов 
Ох, благодарю. Значит буду разбираться с digits3. А использовал я Microsoft Visual Studio. Благодарю!

Comment: @Witson Я этого - перевода string в int - не вижу (уж очень оно у вас... гм... странное...), потому и просил пояснить, как работает этот ваш код и что вы хотите получить...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Понимаете, очень странный метод у вас. Разбираться, почему в нем не работает та или иная строка - куда сложнее, чем набросать нормальное решение.

Если строка - положительное натуральное число, а в случае сбоев (ну, там, буква среди цифр) как признак этого возвращаем -1, то этих нескольких строк вполне достаточно:

```
int string_to_number(const std::string& s)
{
    int res = 0;
    for(char c: s)
        if (c < '0' || c > '9') return -1; else res = res*10+c-'0';
    return res;
}
```

Это не ответ на ваш вопрос "не могу понять, почему динамический массив не заполняется", потому что там динамический массив вообще не нужен...

Comment: Ну кстати - да. Я как-то не догадался отнять '0'. Куда конечно более элегантное решение, чем мои сравнивания. И поочерёдное добавление нуля, вместо перемножений на 1000/100/10/1 в зависимости от положения.
Благодарю!

Comment: Ну, если ответ вас устроил - слева от него есть такая симпатичная птичка, которая станет еще симпатичнее - зеленой - после того, как вы щелнете на ней мышкой. Попробуйте :)

Comment: Пытался апвоутнуть, но не вышло. Рейтинг не тот.

Comment: А как если отрицательное число?

Comment: @Witson проверить первый знак - не минус ли... Или не плюс :)

Answer (score 0):

В итоге у меня такой монстр получился:

```
int string_to_number(const std::string& s) {
    int strnum = s.size();//выявляю размер стринг
    int *ary = new int[strnum];//создаю динамический массив ary
    int digits[11] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, -1 };//создаю массив всех цифр
    int digits2[11] = { 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 45 };//создаю массив ранвых по значению в int цифр char
    int digits3[10] = { 1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000, 10000000, 100000000, 1000000000 };//создаю массив для финального результата
    int digits4[11] = { 1, 1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000, 10000000, 100000000, 1000000000 };
    for (int a = 0; a < strnum; a++) {
        ary[a] = s[a];//приравниваю значения s в динамический массив ary
    }
    for (int a = 0; a < strnum; a++) {
        for (int b = 0; b < 11; b++) {
            if (ary[a] == digits2[b]) {//сраниваю показатели digits2 и ary
                ary[a] = digits[b];//перевожу значения в цифровые
            }
        }
    }
    int b = strnum - 1;
    if (ary[0] > 0) {
        for (int a = 0; a < strnum; a++) {
            ary[a] = ary[a] * digits3[b];//перемножаю 
            b--;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (int a = 1; a < strnum; a++) {
            ary[a] = ary[a] * digits4[b];//перемножаю 
            b--;
        }
    }
    int result = 0;
    if (ary[0] > 0) {
        for (int a = 0; a < strnum; a++) {
            result = result + ary[a];
        }
    }
    else {
        for (int a = 1; a < strnum; a++) {
            result = result + ary[a];
        }
        result *= -1;
    }
    delete[] ary;
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    std::string str = "-721";
    std::cout << "Size of string is " << str.size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << string_to_number(str) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот с корректировкой на @Harry

```
int string_to_number(const std::string& s) {
    int result = 0;
    if (s[0] == '-') {
        for (int a = 1; a < s.size(); a++) {
            result = result * 10 + s[a] - '0';
        }
        result *= -1;
    }
    else {
        for (char c : s) {
            result = result * 10 + c - '0';
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```